# How is boost::asio::write impacted by setting the socket to non-blocking mode?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

If I call `non_blocking(true)` on the socket, and then use `boost::asio::write`, how does the behavior differ from having the socket in blocking mode? Presumably a write can always complete without blocking, because the data to be written is already available.

Answer (score 0):

> *a write can always complete without blocking, because the data to be written is already available*

The data for `write` is always available, that's not the issue. The issue is if there's space available in the NIC send buffer to accept the write immediately or does the program have to wait for the space to become available.

If the latter, in non-blocking mode the write will fail with a `would_block` error. This is also explained in [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/non_blocking/overload2.html):

> `basic_stream_socket::non_blocking`
>
> **mode**
>
> If `true`, the socket's synchronous operations will fail with `boost::asio::error::would_block` if they are unable to perform the requested operation immediately. If `false`, synchronous operations will block until complete.